# MNIST object has no attribute data

Tags: mnist, torchvision

I am trying to run the piece of code given below but unfortunately I get the following error- "MNIST object has no attribute data". The error is because of the line "mnist_train_set.data.view(-1, 1, 28, 28).float()". Can someone shed some light on how to fix this? Thanks.

```py
import torch
from torchvision import datasets

...

mnist_train_set = datasets.MNIST(data_dir + '/mnist/', train = True, download = True)
mnist_test_set = datasets.MNIST(data_dir + '/mnist/', train = False, download = True)

train_input = mnist_train_set.data.view(-1, 1, 28, 28).float()
train_target = mnist_train_set.targets
test_input = mnist_test_set.data.view(-1, 1, 28, 28).float()
test_target = mnist_test_set.targets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution: instead of **data** use **train_data** for train_input, **train_labels** for train_target, **test_data** for test_input, **test_labels** for test_target. I have run the following code without an error.

```
train_input = mnist_train_set.train_data.view(-1, 1, 28, 28).float()
train_target = mnist_train_set.train_labels
test_input = mnist_test_set.test_data.view(-1, 1, 28, 28).float()
test_target = mnist_test_set.test_labels
```

Answer (score 3):

I have run into this same error - it's a torchvision versioning issue.

In the current version of torchvision (0.4.0), the dataset x and y properties are called "data" and "targets".

In the previous version of torchvision (0.3.0), the dataset x and y properties were called either "train_data" and "train_labels", or "test_data" and "test_labels" (depending on which you specified to be loaded).

To fix your code, use latest torchvision or change it to use previous version property names.